# Calling javascript function inside jquery ajax response file code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, response

I am trying to call `date_cal()` javascript function inside ajax response (wall_list.php).Every thing is fine am getting correct response. But its not calling date_cal() function.

main file:

$.ajax({

```
  url: 'wall_list.php',
  data:"dt_from="+dt_from+"&dt_to="+dt_to+"&week="+week+"&month="+month+"&dt_filter="+dt_filter+"&fan="+fan+"&gender="+gender+"&pageNumber="+pagenumber,
  type: 'POST',
success: function (resp) { 

if(resp)
{
 //alert(resp);
  document.getElementById('wall_listdiv').innerHTML=resp;

}
```

> Wall_list.php
>
> Some code...................

```
>   <td id="<?php print $key; ?>" class="tm_td" valign="top" colspan=2>
>   

    <script language="JavaScript">
                                date_cal('<?php print $commentcreatetimearr[$key]; ?>','<?php print $key; ?>');
                                </script>

>       </td>
```

> Some code......................

it's not calling javascript there.

Can anyone explain how to all this function in response.

Comment: are you sure, the code is interpreted as javascript? I can't see script tags here :)

Comment: but nevertheless... if you are looking for a cross-browser solution to execute code you send back in an AJAX response, you probably will endup with using eval()...

Comment: see now there was problem. now corrected question

Comment: you could also pass the arguments to the function back in the response as JSON and call date_cal() in your success function!?

Comment: It's calling dynamically based on param comming from '<?php print $commentcreatetimearr[$key]; ?> in a loop

Comment: well, I think you have to consider another approach... you are only injecting the JS code into the existing document, thus no interpreter is executing it. What does date_cal do? Does it really depend on the content of the current document?

Comment: Content is nothing just a mysql query fetching data and am showing that is table. in data ther is date/time value for that i am using this javascript function to change date format nothing else.

Comment: format the time using php's date-function... It will save you from a lot of trouble :)

Comment: Just pass the $commentcreatetimearr[$key] (without the script tags) back and call date_call from the callback function

Comment: @paul : I have to show date/time  according to client browser.

Comment: @Andy: can you show example how ?

Comment: @Alfred, Andy's solution is what I meant with JSON... This might be the simplest solution...

Comment: @Andy & Paul: Can u please paste some example code here or any link for such example. I have never done such task with JSON. and no idea about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example
php:

```
<?php echo $commentcreatetimearr[$key]; ?>
```

js:

```
$.ajax({    
  url: 'wall_list.php',
  data:"dt_from="+dt_from+"&dt_to="+dt_to+"&week="+week+"&month="+month+"&dt_filter="+dt_filter+"&fan="+fan+"&gender="+gender+"&pageNumber="+pagenumber,
  type: 'POST',
success: function (resp) {     
  if(resp){
     $('#wall_listdiv').html(date_cal(resp));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

here you go

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'wall_list.php',
    data: "dt_from="+dt_from+"&dt_to="+dt_to+"&week="+week+"&month="+month+"&dt_filter="+dt_filter+"&fan="+fan+"&gender="+gender+"&pageNumber="+pagenumber,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (resp){
        if(resp){
            $("#wall_listdiv").html(resp);
        }
    },
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

What you want to do is, specify the return `dataType` as `html`. 
From jQuery API

```
If html is specified, any embedded JavaScript inside the retrieved data is executed before the HTML is returned as a string. Similarly, script will execute the JavaScript that is pulled back from the server, then return the script itself as textual data.
```

More information here: [jQuery.ajax() - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)