# Parsing Ajax response of a php file and calling a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I would like to call a function on a php file, which one I call in ajax.
 I tried the following code:

```
$("#jq_entryConfQuickSend").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        context: document.body,
        //async:false,
        url: RP_ROOT_PATH + "/courriers/entries_courriers/rp_win_courrierEntryConfirmation.php",
        data: "id_client=" + RP_CLIENT.rp_clientID,
        success: function (responseText) {
            //var json = eval("(" + responseText + ")");
            $("#response-div").html(responseText);
            $(responseText).find("script").each(function (i) {
                eval($(this).text());
                console.log('result');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

In `$(responseText)` seems to be an array (I can see the following  e.fn.e.init[58]) in chrome debugger, but when I try to use the find('script') function, it doesn't return anything??
And I have many script tag in these file???

**Question: What is e.fn.e.init[]?**
How can I call my javascript functions on the file I've just loaded in ajax
Thank you

Comment: `e.fn.e.init` is what you see when you `console.log` a jQuery object.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the script tags returned from the PHP file, and then execute them in the page?

Comment: I Found an answer in an other topic: [if somebody is interested][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4733086/calling-javascript-function-inside-jquery-ajax-response-file-code?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ajax parameters I needed to include :

```
dataType: "html"
```

Then it will be possible to call the function from the response